The equivalence of two definitions of Kähler-Einstein metric.
Denote by $\mathbf{Ric}$ the Ricci tensor and ${\rm Ric}$ the Ricci curvature. Their relation is
$${\rm Ric}(X)=\frac1{|X|^2}\mathbf{Ric}(X,\overline X).$$
And we have $\mathbf{Ric}(X,\overline Y)=\overline{\mathbf{Ric}(Y,\overline X)}$.

I saw two definitions of Kähler-Einstein metric. The first definition is a Kähler metric $g$ whose Ricci tensor satisfies
$$\mathbf{Ric}\equiv \lambda g,\quad\lambda\in\mathbb R.$$
The second definition is a Kähler metric $g$ whose Ricci curvature is constant, i.e. for any complex tangent vector $X$,
$${\rm Ric}(X)\equiv \lambda,\quad\lambda\in\mathbb R.$$

Obviously, the first one implies the second one. In Riemannian geometry, the second one also implies the first one since we have polarization formula. But in the complex case, we have
\begin{align*}
\lambda|X+Y|^2&=|X+Y|^2{\rm Ric}(X+Y)=\mathbf{Ric}(X+Y,\overline{X+Y})\\
&=\mathbf{Ric}(X,\overline X)+\mathbf{Ric}(Y,\overline Y)+\mathbf{Ric}(X,\overline Y)+\mathbf{Ric}(Y,\overline X)\\
&=|X|^2{\rm Ric}(X)+|Y|^2{\rm Ric}(Y)+\mathbf{Ric}(X,\overline Y)+\overline{\mathbf{Ric}(X,\overline Y)}\\
&=\lambda(|X|^2+|Y|^2)+2~{\rm Re}~\mathbf{Ric}(X,\overline Y).
\end{align*}
So we only get
$${\rm Re}~\mathbf{Ric}(X,\overline Y)=\lambda{\rm Re}~g(X,\overline Y).$$
I think I may have missed something very trivial. Any help would be appreciated!

I forgot to consider ${\rm Ric}(X+iY)$ at first.
\begin{align*}
\lambda|X+iY|^2&=|X+iY|^2{\rm Ric}(X+iY)=\mathbf{Ric}(X+iY,\overline{X+iY})\\
&=\mathbf{Ric}(X,\overline X)+\mathbf{Ric}(Y,\overline Y)-i\mathbf{Ric}(X,\overline Y)+i\mathbf{Ric}(Y,\overline X)\\
&=\lambda(|X|^2+|Y|^2)+2~{\rm Im}~\mathbf{Ric}(X,\overline Y).
\end{align*}
So we get
$${\rm Im}~\mathbf{Ric}(X,\overline Y)=\lambda{\rm Im}~g(X,\overline Y).$$
Therefore
$$\mathbf{Ric}(X,\overline Y)=\lambda g(X,\overline Y).$$

PS: The polarization formula for the conjugate symmetry case is
$$B(u,\bar v)=\frac12A(u+v)+\frac12A(u+iv)-A(u)-A(v).$$
